# facebook login button not rendering

Tags: facebook

Hi 
I am developing a widget that will be placed on an external website. The entire plugin has to be written in javascript. I haev searched here and there but am unable to make the facebook login button appear on the widget

My code is the following

```
    var fbroot = document.createElement('div');
        fbroot.id = "fb-root";
        window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
            FB.init('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '/xd_receiver.htm');       
        };

    var contentRightDiv = document.createElement('div');
    contentRightDiv.id = "contentrightdiv";
    contentRightDiv.innerHTML = "<form><p><label>Sign in using <div id='socialmedialoginbtns'></div></label></p></form>";

var socialmedialoginbtns = document.getElementById('socialmedialoginbtns');
    socialmedialoginbtns.innerHTML = '<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>';
```

Comment: Have you registered your app on facebook and got an AppId, and did you include fb's all.js?

Answer (score 2):

If you are putting an XFBML tag on the document with javascript, use FB.XFBML.parse function to render the new tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Code snippet....

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript">`
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'Your_App_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({appId: 'Your_App_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

      /* All the events registered */
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        getUserDetails();
        login();
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        logout();
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
          // logged in and connected user, someone you know
          login();
        }
      });
    };

    </script>
    <fb:login-button 
      autologoutlink="true" 
      perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream">
    </fb:login-button>
  </body>
</html>
```